# What difference between select and without select in NgRx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have two ways usually use when I subscribe to a state of a store.
Is it any difference between them (like performance or something)

```js
constructor(private store : Store<MyState>){
    //1
    this.store.pipe(select(x=>x.myComplexObject)).subscribe(x=> {
        this.data = x;
    })
    //2
    this.store.subscribe(x=> {
        this.data = x.myComplexObject;
    })
}
```

Comment: You could also go for the slightly less verbose Option this.store.select(x=>x.myComplexObject).subscribe(x=>...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are the same.
But, I would suggest moving to `selectors` because these have several advantages:

- multiple selectors can be combined
- easy to test
- performant because it's memoized

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors